# How can I compare two different csv file using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, compare, axis

I want to make the code that compare two csv files!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    df = pd.read_csv("E:\Dupfile.csv")
    df1 = pd.read_csv("E:\file.csv")
    
    df['Correct'] = None
    
    def Result(x):
       if ....:
         return int(1)
       else:
         return int(0)
    
    
    df.loc[:,"Correct"]=df.apply(Result,axis=1)
    
    print(df["Correct"])
    
    df.to_csv("E:\file.csv")
    print(df.head(20))
```

For example, file.csv format seems like below:

```
     round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth  
0     1  2021.04      1      14     15      24     40     41     
1     2  2021.04      2       9     10      16     35     37      
2     3  2021.04      4      15     24      35     36     40      
3     4  2021.03     10      11     20      21     25     41     
4     5  2021.03      4       9     23      26     29     33     
5     6  2021.03      1       9     26      28     30     41
```

Dupfile.csv seems like below:

```
    round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth  
0     1  2021.04      1      14     15      24     40     41  
0     1  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6    
1     2  2021.04      2       9     10      16     35     37   
1     2  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6      
2     3  2021.04      4      15     24      35     36     40    
2     3  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6     
3     4  2021.03     10      11     20      21     25     41  
3     4  2021.03      1       2      3       4      5      6     
4     5  2021.03      4       9     23      26     29     33  
4     5  2021.03      1       2      3       4      5      6
```

it has one more same round, but value is different.

check the file's round value with Dupfile's round and if the first to sixth value is equal, make the another "Correct" column in Dupfile and put 1. If not correct, put 0 to the "Correct" Column.

I tried to compare two different csv file but, I don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me?

my expectation answer:

```
    round    date  first  second  third  fourth  fifth  sixth Correct
0     1  2021.04      1      14     15      24     40     41    1
0     1  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6    0
1     2  2021.04      2       9     10      16     35     37    1
1     2  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6    0  
2     3  2021.04      4      15     24      35     36     40    1
2     3  2021.04      1       2      3       4      5      6    0 
3     4  2021.03     10      11     20      21     25     41    1
3     4  2021.03      1       2      3       4      5      6    0 
4     5  2021.03      4       9     23      26     29     33    1
4     5  2021.03      1       2      3       4      5      6    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `pandas` module, it will be better to gain the methods that provide in the module. I suggest you, try to use `merge` for comparing 2 different DataFrames. I rewrite your code as follows.

```all
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("E:\Dupfile.csv")
df1 = pd.read_csv("E:\file.csv")

df1['Correct'] = 1

df = df.merge(
        df1,
        how='left',
        on=['round',
            'date',
            'first',
            'second',
            'third',
            'fourth',
            'fifth',
            'sixth']).fillna(0)

print(df)

print(df['Correct'])

df.to_csv("E:\file.csv")
print(df.head(20))
```

### How does it work?

The `merge` method tries to match the columns in `df` and `df1` with the same names that exist in `on` array. When you select `left` for `how` argument, no values on the left side of merging (`df`) would be removed (Left Join). In another way, the `correct` column that we create in `file.csv` appends to `Dupfil.csv` data, and non-match is assigned as `nan` value. The `fillna(0)` method helps us to replace `nan` values with 0.

[pandas.DataFrame.merge API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure pandas using `df.merge`.

Check out the example:

```
import pandas as pd


# file.csv
file_df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["round", "date", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"],
    data=[
        ("1", "2021.04", "1", "14", "15", "24", "40", "41"),
        ("2", "2021.04", "2", "9", "10", "16", "35", "37"),
        ("3", "2021.04", "4", "15", "24", "35", "36", "40"),
        ("4", "2021.03", "10", "11", "20", "21", "25", "41"),
        ("5", "2021.03", "4", "9", "23", "26", "29", "33"),
        ("6", "2021.03", "1", "9", "26", "28", "30", "41"),
    ],
)

# adding control column (we already know that those are the right values)
file_df["correct"] = 1

# Dupfile.csv
dup_file_df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["round", "date", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth", "sixth"],
    data=[
        ("1", "2021.04", "1", "14", "15", "24", "40", "41"),
        ("1", "2021.04", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        ("2", "2021.04", "2", "9", "10", "16", "35", "37"),
        ("2", "2021.04", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        ("3", "2021.04", "4", "15", "24", "35", "36", "40"),
        ("3", "2021.04", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        ("4", "2021.03", "10", "11", "20", "21", "25", "41"),
        ("4", "2021.03", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
        ("5", "2021.03", "4", "9", "23", "26", "29", "33"),
        ("5", "2021.03", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
    ],
)

# We extract the column names to use in the merging process
cols = [x for x in dup_file_df.columns]

# We merge the 2 dataframes.
# The data frames are to match on every column (round, date and first to sixth). 
# The "correct" column will be populated only if all the columns are matching
merged = dup_file_df.merge(file_df, how="outer", left_on=cols, right_on=cols)

# We put "0" where correct is None and cast to integer (it was float)
merged["correct"] = merged["correct"].fillna(0).astype(int)

# Done!
print(merged)
```